# NSolid docker image cannot resolve hostname

Tags: node.js, nsolid

I have been trying to setup Nsolid docker images. Did the following:

- pulled all the three docker images
- built my application with FROM nodesource/nsolid:latest
- run all the docker images as stated here: https://docs.nodesource.com/nsolid/1.2/docs/using-the-images-without-docker-compose
- then I run my docker image as mentioned on the above document and I run into error that it could not resolve the host name.

  [ERROR] Resolving hostname to IP address has encountered an error:
  EAI_NONAME (unknown node or service)

  on ../nsolid-ext/deps/agent/src/etcd_connector.cc:302
  *** Error in `node': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001f551f8 ***

Please suggest how I can approach this issue. Did not find any help information in the docs.

Comment: Did you ran Console succesfully? Need to run 3 containers, so can you make them run correctly? Is the error running the container with your image?

Comment: Yes I was able to run the console successfully. The error happens when I run the container with my image.

Comment: Sorry the delay here. Seems then that the issue is the container of your app can't reach the registry container. Make sure you are adding `--net nsolid` to your command to make the container in the same network, then make sure you have `NSOLID_HUB=registry:4001` so the nsolid instance can connect to the main registry. Let me know how it goes